# Do Falcon 9s get a thorough wash or a fresh coat of paint (they look clean pre-reflight)?

Tags: falcon-9, reuse

Before/[during](https://www.flickr.com/photos/spacex/51160802949/) reflight, the boosters look white and clean, but [after](https://www.reddit.com/r/SpaceXLounge/comments/nb4dt3/i_think_electron_rockets_are_whiter_than_b105110/), they don't. I'm not sure if that's soot and/or burned paint.

I [looked](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=falcon%20wash%20paint) but it doesn't seem to have been asked before.

---

RE [Is Falcon 9 repainted before reuse?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48304/32596) It does not address the clean look I mentioned, which it turns out based on an [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/52142/32596) here is due to the late coverage start with ice/frost already formed.

Comment: The refurbished boosters don't look that nice, so we can rule out a fresh coat of paint. Not even for [crewed launches](https://www.flickr.com/photos/spacex/51136428854/). They wear their scars with pride, [it seems](https://mma.prnewswire.com/media/1373982/SXM_7_Ready_For_Launch.jpg?p=publish).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Falcon 9 repainted before reuse?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48304/is-falcon-9-repainted-before-reuse)

Comment: @FredLarson: No sorry, but I edited why. Thanks though!

Comment: [Here](https://i.redd.it/lheh45odwqy61.jpg) is a photo of a Falcon 9 booster after its 10th (tenth!) flight. As you can see, it is absolutely filthy - and we can tell that that isn't all from its most recent flight, because the parts that _have_ been cleaned (welds and the like, as Jorg says) show up very clearly.

Comment: It's worth noting that the space shuttle was originally painted (and the paint refurbished after every flight).  It didn't take long for NASA to realize that all the paint did was add weight.  I could find much on-line about this other than this estimation exercise for students: https://opencurriculum.org/9378/how-much-does-the-paint-on-a-space-shuttle-weigh/

Comment: @Flydog57: Ah yes. It was the [External Tank](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2449/32596).

Comment: As an aside: paint weighs more than you would expect. As an example, the paint on a 747 supposedly weighs around 545kg ([source](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=213565)). I'm not sure how much the paint weighs on the Falcon 9, but I would expect they would have to strip all of the existing paint off before applying a fresh coat if they were to repaint it, otherwise the additional weight would decrease efficiency, and maybe (speculation on my part) affect calculations performed during the landing burn.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's easy to see by just looking at photos and videos of launches of re-used boosters that they don't. There are only a very few very small white lines, probably where engineers inspected some weld lines or other specific points on the vehicle.

[Here is an example of B1061.2 launching the Crew-2 mission](https://youtu.be/lW07SN3YoLI?t=1112). Note that this is only the second launch of this booster, and it is already pretty dirty.

You can also see it on returning boosters, which are dirtier the more often they have flown, which would not be the case if they were cleaned every time.

Unfortunately, it is not that easy to see it on a [normal SpaceX live stream](https://youtu.be/J71s2KmkSrc?t=693) because they only start the streams about 10 minutes before launch when fueling is already underway (starting at T-34 minutes) and the booster is already fully covered in ice. You *can* see it on live streams from other sources, though, [here for example from NASASpaceflight.com](https://youtu.be/GPMqJki82KQ?t=75) and [Stephen Marr (launch and return to port)](https://twitter.com/spacecoast_stve/status/1392650988884987913).

Comment: *and the booster is already fully covered in ice* – this is it then. Great analysis and links, thanks!

Comment: Like a good cake if it's slightly burned: Put some icing on top!

Answer (score 15):

The first Falcon 9 re-flights they were made to look white and clean. Using [Wikipedia's Falcon launch history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Falcon_9_and_Falcon_Heavy_launches) and Google Images SES-10, BulgariaSat-1, and SES-11/EchoStar 105 all look spotless. CRS-13 ("internal" customer) is dirty, but not as dirty as nowadays. The Falcon Heavy side boosters (for the first test launch) were re-flown but probably required significant overhaul and are thus spotless. After those all re-flights seem to be dirty.